# Azure SQL Database Deployment Task Takes Significantly More Time To Finish After Datacenter Migration

Tags: azure-devops, azure-sql-database

We have an established pipeline for database deployment on Azure DevOps. The usual deployment time is about 1 min 30 sec to the North Europe datacenter.
Recently we changed datacenter to the UAE North due to client requirements. After the migration deployment time increased to almost 30 minutes. As I understand, we need to change pipeline location and make it closer to the database, but I can't find such setting.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if it solves your issue. But if you want to change a region you should use [`Azure DevOps Virtual Support Agent.`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/accounts/change-organization-location?view=azure-devops). But please keep in mind that now all regions are supported for a change:

> A region change is only possible in the following geographies across the world:
>
> - Australia
> - Brazil
> - Canada
> - Asia Pacific
> - Europe
> - India
> - United Kingdom
> - United States

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, but this approach won't suit us as we have multiple projects and moving whole organization repository will affect other pipelines.